# generate matrix and populate data using dataframe pyspark

Tags: dataframe, matrix, pyspark, using

I need to generate a 34x34 matrix from dataframe and i am using pyspark to accomplish this

Below is the sample data set currently i have

```
custid     numbertimesvistied    day             pagevisited
1111            2              06102019          flightticket
1111            1              06102019          menu
1111            2              06102019          booking
1111            6              06102019          cancel
1111            2              06102019          flightticket
```

i am expecting a matrix from the above data as below

```
              flightticket      menu     booking      cancel
flightticket    0                 2          0            0
menu            0                 0          2            0
booking         0                 0          0            6
cancel          2                 0          0            0
```

I tried to use pandas then iterate overeach row and compare and compute , however unable to make a progress

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(df['custid']!=df['custid'].shift()):
     then compute a columval here and assign it to respective matrix value
```

currently no issues however i am looking to get opinion on what is the best way to achive it

Comment: Could you explain the algorithm how do you go from the first DataFrame to the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

i will compare first event with next event untill i reached to end of the customer events then cummulative sum of these events will be aligned against customer

## example:

Cust        page_event     flightticket      menu     booking      cancel

1111        flightticket     0                 2          0            0

1111         menu            0                 0          2            0

1111         booking         0                 0          0            6

1111        cancel           2                 0          0            0

and need to iterate over all the customers